# How to add .htaccess rules inside <VirtualHost> or inside the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

A short explanation of what I'm doing is: I need to automatically create virtualhosts for each ip address on my machine, make it point to the vsftpd user directory (/home/xxx) and deny any kind of scripts from being executed.

I want to stop any kind of webpages and especially PHP scripts from being executed, because it would post a huge security risk(apache is sudo). The purpose of this virtualhost is purely to serve game resource files, extentions like .wav , .mdl , .tga , .spr and so on.

I searched around and found this

```
deny from all 
<filesmatch "\.(avi¦wmv¦mpg¦mov)$"> 
Allow from all 
</filesmatch>
```

But this is .htaccess content. How can I implement this functionality of only allowing certain extentions inside my httpd.conf file? It would be a pain to make it use .htaccess, and a risk because users might edit them.

Please refrain from any comments unrelated to my question, such as "sudo apache? you're a dumbass" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as .htaccess only content. The is a huge misconception. Most of time you do **NOT** want to use `.htaccess` and Apache recommends that you not use it unless necessary. Apache rules can always be put in the server config.

[When not to use .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Now you can put that in your VirtualHost directive. The same location where your document root is defined.

The FilesMatch directive can be used in these context.

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch

So in your vhost file you can add a Directory directive like this example.

```
<Directory /path/to/documentroot/>
   Deny from all 
  <FilesMatch "\.(avi|wmv|mpg|mov)$"> 
   Allow from all 
  </FilesMatch> 
</Directory>
```

If you are using `Apache 2.4` then you need to use `Require`.

```
<Directory /path/to/documentroot/>
   Require all denied
  <FilesMatch "\.(avi|wmv|mpg|mov)$"> 
   Require all granted 
  </FilesMatch> 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @panama-jack . Regarding the directories, I use var/www for the main website the box hosts. If I were to have 40 other virtual hosts, all inside /home/ , could I just make one rule only for /home/ or do I need to add one entry for each document root specified in vhost, eg /home/user/web. Also will this rule apply to every subfolder as well?. Edit:: tested and it works with one rule only for /home/ , if you have anything to add, please do so. Thank you again

Comment: It should work if you use a parent directory `/home/` as you discovered. So if that meets your requirement then you should be good to go. :) Nothing more to add if it's working for you. I hope the answer helped you out.